# In an interpreter, what (usually) comes after the lexer?

Tags: design-patterns, language-design, interpreter

For a programming language interpreter, I am wondering about the sequence of events that the interpreter goes through. For instance, I think this is how it goes:

- Interpreter gets some input
- The lexer/tokenizer gets the input and demarcates the tokens
- The *x* gets the list of tokens
- ???
- The code gets executed

What step(s) belongs in the ??? spot, and what goes in the place of *x* (that is, what recieves and operates on the tokens that the lexer has produced)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start by recommending the classic and free book: [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) ([video lectures](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/))

Lisp is the baseline interpreter and everything else is a in some ways a variation on the theme.

In general the steps are:

- Lexical analysis take a char stream and produces tokens
- Parsing takes the tokens (a flat list) and builds a data structure called an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST). This step can be very easy (Lisp) or amazingly complex (C++, Ruby).
- Evaluate the AST. The details are a bit different but this is pretty much a depth first walk down the tree.  Leaves are `data` (numbers, strings, constants, variables) nodes are either primitive functions (math, data manipulation, control structures) or higher level compound functions. Each node should reduce to something that can be fed directly into the node above it.

This last step *is* "code gets executed." For a compiled or Just-In-Time (JIT) language the last step is instead translating the AST back into machine instructions.  It is also important to note two other steps that may be present.  One is a translation into a simpler language like c--, LLVM, .NET, or Java bitecode. The other is desugaring and/or optimization that can happen between the parser and the evaluator. Haskell for example is somewhat infamous for the huge amount of desugaring that goes on.

I'll end by encouraging you to try one of the many walk-throughs for writing a Scheme (a dialect of Lisp) interpreter.  There is likely one for your favorite language on the net somewhere.

Comment: Old question but a good answer. I wish this was the first one posted.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing happens, to turn the stream of tokens into structured, validated, syntactic information. If you want to evaluate, say, an arithmetic expression:

`(` `x` `+` `4` `)` `*` `3`

you don’t do it by scanning the tokens from left to right. You need to figure out order of operations. You need to turn the tokens between an `if` keyword and the `{` `}` curly braces into a high-level structure describing the if statement, so you can evaluate it without juggling a pile of tokens. And you need to check the syntax, which is essentially impossible without properly parsing it; please read about *context-free grammars*.

The expression above would become an *abstract syntax tree* like the following:

```
    *
  +   3
 x y
```

Evaluating this is pretty simple — just traverse the tree, and look up `x` and `y` in the environment.

Similarly, given a series of statements like this:

`if` `(` `p` `&&` `q` `)` `{` `foo` `;` `bar` `;` `}` `else` `{` `baz` `;` `}`

the abstract syntax tree might have the following general structure:

```
IfStatement:
  Condition:
    LogicalConjunction:
      LeftOperand: p
      RightOperand: q
  TruePart:
    BasicBlock:
      Statement: foo
      Statement: bar
  FalsePart:
    BasicBlock:
      Statement: baz
```

Hopefully you can imagine how you would traverse this tree to interpret the code.

A textbook on interpreters which I highly recommend is [*Essentials of Programming Languages*](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/eopl/).

Comment: So, the parser basically puts everything in order so that it can be logically looked at without worrying about the validity or order of anything (because it has already been ordered and validated)?

Comment: Both to verify the syntax, and because that’s a necessary step for any interesting language. An interpreter which rejects no programs is a boring one.

Comment: Because what's a necessary step for any good language, validating syntax? And by the way this answer is very helpful.

Comment: Parsing. In principle, if you stopped at the list of tokens, you could scan ahead from `else` to the next matching `}`, but the steps required to do that are just about those of a parser. Besides, in a language that has function calls or variable declarations, you need to put those into an environment so you can find them later, which is also facilitated by parsing.

Answer (score 1):

For an interpreter the parser will generally do two things

1. Generate p-code
2. Add items to the symbol table

After this the `executor` will execute the p-code and lookup identifiers etc. in the symbol table.

The parser parses the stream of tokens it receives and generates the simpler more efficient to execute `p-code` at the same time any symbols like variables, functions, complex data type structures etc. that are found during the parsing phase are entered into the symbol table and referenced in the p-code.

The executor then processes the stream of p-code and executes the instructions and uses the symbol table to lookup any identifiers it encounters in the symbol table.